# How can I use onkeypress without javascript embedded into the html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For unique reasons, I cannot use any javascript in my HTML (IE no onclick=function(), no onkeypress=function() etc). I need to use the function
         `return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57`
to ensure that the user can only type numbers into a textbox. I've tried:

```
           $('#mobile').onkeypress = function () {
               return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57
           };
```

which was sitting under a (document).ready function.

My original (working) code looked like this:

```
onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' style="width:210px;">
```

Note: I can still use javascript it just has to be embedded seperately. I am copy pasting html into Sharepoint 2013 (without designer and infopath) and it only allows you to upload html and javascript seperately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('#mobile').on("keypress", function (event) {
    return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57
});
```

Comment: And indeed may prefer to use keycode, or use something like  event.charCode || event.keyCode;

Comment: I thought I tried that exactly before but I tried it there and it worked. I must have had an error somewhere, cheers! Ah I left out (event).

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass in the event that you are referencing to the function as follows:

```
$('#mobile').onkeypress = function (event) {
           return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57
       };
```

Also event.charCode is deprecated ([SOURCE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode)). You might want to use event.keyCode instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$('#mobile').onkeypress = function (e) {
  return e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57
};
```